# how to change layers for the same background scene

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a menu for my cocos2d game. I would like to know if there is a way I can change layers within the same scene, similar to the pop and replace scene? I want to use this approach to keep the background unchanged as I navigate through the main menu hierarchy. How can I achieve this? I wouldn't mind another approach that would be more effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no specific mechanism; just keep a reference to each layer inside your class, add them to the root scene, and show/hide them in the right moment.

Comment: Thanks. Hiding and showing layers would require a layer at each hierarchy level. That's a lot of layers.